# How to refresh page without finish?

Tags: android

I am using this code to refresh and this code refreshes the page but I am unable to go to another page as it keeps reloading the same page. I want it to auto refresh the page only when I click it and I want to be able to move to other pages.

```
enter code here
 public void refresh(int milliseconds){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            finish();
            overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
            startActivity(getIntent());
            overridePendingTransition( 0, 0);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,milliseconds);
}
```

Comment: please post the code where you added the function above.

Comment: You can use recreate() function, it will directly refresh the activity. >API11

Answer (score 0):

Instead of closing and re-opening your activity, you just **update the UI with the relevant data.**

You could also use `LiveData` and `ViewModel` so that the data will always appear on screen instead of you manually checking if new data is available.

### LiveData

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata

> LiveData is an observable data holder class. Unlike a regular
>   observable, LiveData is lifecycle-aware, meaning it respects the
>   lifecycle of other app components, such as activities, fragments, or
>   services. This awareness ensures LiveData only updates app component
>   observers that are in an active lifecycle state.

Answer (score 0):

@Daniel answer is very reasonable, however, if you still want to reload the page for god-knows-what purposes you can do this many ways without starting a new thread!!

implement `SwipeToRefreshLayout`, better than starting a new thread
then

```
mySwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(
    new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            doYourUpdate();
            //Or Just call
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());

        }
    }
);
```

or if you are using a button just call

```
finish();
startActivity(getIntent());
```

you can implement `startActivity(getIntent());` without `finish();` , but becareful about adding useless activities to your stack..

Answer (score 0):

When you want to refresh the data, please use LiveData as Daniel B. says.
You are currently destroying the activity with `finish()` and trying to start the same activity again. The `finish()` method initiates the `onDestroy()` method in the activity lifecycle. So call this method at the end. **Your way is not how to refresh data of an activity.**

But if you want to restart the activity on button clicked, see the code below:

```
void restartActivity(View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityClassWhichYouWantToStart.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void refresh(int milliseconds){
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            recreate();
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(runnable,milliseconds);
}
```